# How can I remove doller sign from WooCommerce product add-on plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently I install Woocommerce in WordPress and Woocommerce Products addon I face a Problem Using Woocommerce I face a Problem with currency I have Attached a Screenshot for the Problem Please someone help to solve this problem for every Products https://prnt.sc/wbanea

Website Url Is https://www.eezyposte.com/

When I Check source code I saw there is Span code inserted a $ sign but I am not able to find the Error how this sign is appear I tried to hide through CSS but I am Not Able to do that Please someone Help me To removed this $ sign or Removed the Complete "Total global:" Options Please anyone help me for doing this job done I am not able to do it thanks

Answer (score 1):

[enter link description here](https://www.eezyposte.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-addons-master/assets/js/addons.min.js?ver=1.0) look at this file.
your problem is woocommerce_addons_params.price_display_suffix

Comment: Can I remove This suffix, because I already set a default Euro currency but I am not able to understand how can I removed this $ sign

Comment: @GOST yes, you can set window.woocommerce_addons_params.price_display_suffix = ''; in end of </head> tag in your template. regards

Comment: That means i have to add "window.woocommerce_addons_params.price_display_suffix = ''; to the head section in my website?

Comment: yes, end of <head> tag

Comment: After Inset This window.woocommerce_addons_params.price_display_suffix = ''; there is a error I can show you just check https://prnt.sc/wc99ls

Comment: sorry add this end of body tag `(footer.php)`. you dont forget <script> tag, `<script>window.woocommerce_addons_params.price_display_suffix = '';</script>`

Comment: Not Change anymore https://prnt.sc/wc9dyu

Comment: Yes Sir It's working Fine Thanks I just Missing somethings